# How can I reduce the size of a picture in half?

Tags: python-3.x

The error I keep receiving is that the variable must be an integer, not a tuple, but yet when I try to type cast the variable to an integer, the program still says that it is a float. In the end, I am trying to figure out how to reduce the size of a picture by half, so if someone knows how to do that without even addressing the type casting issue just show me how I can do it please.

```
from PIL import Image

image0 = Image.open("cwu_logo0.jpg")

image0Width = image0.width
image0Height = image0.height

print(image0Width)
print(image0Height)

image0Width2 = (image0Width)/10
int(image0Width2)
print(image0Width2)

print(type(image0Width2))
image0Resized = image0.resize((image0Width/2, image0Height/2))
image0Resized.show()
```

here is the output in case anyone wanted it.

```
runfile('C:/Users/12532/Desktop/Python 2020/Lab 10/ImageConverter.py', wdir='C:/Users/12532/Desktop/Python 2020/Lab 10')
300
154
30.0
<class 'float'>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\12532\Desktop\Python 2020\Lab 10\ImageConverter.py", line 20, in <module>
    image0Resized = image0.resize((image0Width/2, image0Height/2))

  File "C:\Users\12532\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1929, in resize
    return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))

TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `image0Resized = image0.resize((int(image0Width/2), int(image0Height/2)))`. The error is caused by division returning a float, which is unsupported by `.resize`.